# How to kill application using os module in python (ironpython 2.7)

Tags: python, operating-system, ironpython, psutil

I was able to kill the VLC media player using the `psutil` module but I have to run my script through ironpython 2.7 and psutil isn't supported.

Is there way I can kill any VLC application that is open using the `os` module or the `subprocess` module? I tried looking into subprocess.terminate but they wanted the file path of what vlc was playing and I wouldn't know that at that time. (if that makes any sense)

Here is the code I used to kill VLC using psutil, any suggestions or ideas would be awesome:

```
import psutil

for process in (process for process in psutil.process_iter() if process.name()=="vlc.exe"):
    process.kill()
```

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question! (Although, if someone has something more pythonic for my situation let me know)

Create a batch file that kills the process for you and use subprocess.call() to execute the program:

Batch file:

```
@echo on

taskkill /F /IM vlc.exe

@end
```

Python example:

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.call(r"""\\VGMSTATION\Users\VGMPC2\Documents\scripts\Kill_VLC.bat""")
```